# Factoring using Extended difference of squares

Tags: algorithms

Given a composite number $P$ and two integers $x$ and $y$ such that: $x^2 = y^2 \pmod P$ we can factor $P$ using factor = $\mathrm{gcd}(P, x-y)$ or $\mathrm{gcd}(P, x+y)$.

Now are there a similar relation where we are given multiple $(x_i, y_i)$ pairs such that:

1. $(x_i^2 - y_i^2) \pmod P = r_i$ (where $r_i \neq 0$)
2. We can still combine and use these pairs to find a factor of $P$ (in polynomial time) given these pairs (perhaps if the $r_i$'s are small enough or they share some structure with each other and so on).

Essentially a generalization of the congruence of squares.

Comment: Usually we reserve the letter $P$ for prime numbers.